# Sending a sql request on the same page but missing the variable in the WHERE clause

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to update a row in my database. the problem is that I am getting an error from mySQL:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' WHERE activiteitID = ''' at line 4
```

So it isn't getting the "activiteitID" and I don't know why. Can someone tell me what the problem is?

This are the two pages:

"roosters_wijzigen.php"

```
 <?php 
    include ("html_start.php"); 

    $activiteitID = $_GET["activiteitID"];
    $datum = $_POST["datum"];
    $tijd = $_POST["tijd"];
    $vrijwilligerID = $_POST["vrijwilligerID"];
    $werkzaamheid = $_POST["werkzaamheid"];

echo '

<div id="registreer">
    <table cellpadding="5" align="center">
            <tr><th colspan="2" align="left">Activiteit wijzigen:</th></tr>
            <form name="roosters_wijzigen"  method="get" action="roosters_wijziging.php"> ';    

            $query = "SELECT * FROM activiteit WHERE activiteitID = '$activiteitID'; ";
            $result = mysql_query($query); 

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){           
    echo'       <tr>
                <td>Datum</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="50" name="datum" value="'.$row['datum'].' "></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tijd</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="50" name="tijd" value="'.$row['tijd'].' "></input></td>
            </tr> ';
            }
            ?>
            <tr>
            <td>Vrijwilliger</td>
            <td>
                <select name="vrijwilligerID">
                    <?php

                        $vrijwilligerID = $_POST["vrijwilligerID"];

                        $query ="   SELECT voornaam, achternaam, vrijwilligerID
                                    FROM vrijwilliger;";

                        $result = mysql_query($query);

                        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                        echo "<option value=".$row['vrijwilligerID'].">".$row["voornaam"]." ".$row["achternaam"]."</option>";
                        }
                        ?>              
            </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Werkzaamheid</td>
                <?php

                $query = "SELECT werkzaamheid FROM activiteit WHERE activiteitID = '$activiteitID'; ";
                $result = mysql_query($query); 
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){           
                echo '<td><textarea rows="6" cols="39" type="text" name="werkzaamheid">'.$row["werkzaamheid"].'</textarea></td>';}

                ?>
            </tr>
            </tr>
            <tr align="right">
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="reset" value="Wissen">
            <input type="submit" name="verzenden" value="verzenden">
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            Ga <a href="roosters_aanpassen.php" MEDIA=screen>hier</a></br> terug. </br>
            </tr>
            </form>
    </table></br>

<div>
<?php
include ("html_end.php");
?>
```

"roosters_wijziging.php"

```
<?php   
    include ("html_start.php");

    $activiteitID = $_GET["activiteitID"];
    $datum = $_POST["datum"];
    $tijd = $_POST["tijd"];
    $vrijwilligerID = $_POST["vrijwilligerID"];
    $werkzaamheid = $_POST["werkzaamheid"];


    $query ="UPDATE vrijwilliger SET datum = '$datum', 
                                     tijd = '$tijd', 
                                     vrijwilligerID = '$vrijwilligerID', 
                                     werkzaamheid '$werkzaamheid'
                                        WHERE activiteitID = '".$activiteitID."'";
    mysql_query($query) or die ( mysql_error());

    echo '<div id="registreer"> 
    Uw activiteit is succesvol toegevoegd.
    Ga <a href="roosters_aanpassen.php" MEDIA=screen>hier</a></br> terug. 
    </div> ';

    include ("html_end.php");   
?>
<?
/*

if(preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}$/", $datum) === 0 || preg_match("/^([0-9])"."([0-9])"."(\:([0-9])"."([0-9]))$/", $tijd) === 0 || $werkzaamheid !== '') 
    {
    echo '<div id="registreer">';
    echo '<font>datum moet op dit formaat ingevoerd worden: JJJJ-MM-DD<br><font>';
    echo '<font>Tijd moet op dit formaat ingevoerd worden: HH:MM <br><font>';
    echo '<font>U heeft de werkzaamheid niet aangegeven<br><font>';
    }
else{   */
?>
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `=` after `werkzaamheid`:

```
...
werkzaamheid = '$werkzaamheid'
WHERE activiteitID ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not work, but try adding the ` character around your table attributes and table names... Like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `activiteit` WHERE `activiteitID` = '$activiteitID'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"UPDATE vrijwilliger SET datum = '$datum', 
tijd = '$tijd', 
vrijwilligerID = '$vrijwilligerID', 
werkzaamheid '$werkzaamheid'
WHERE activiteitID = '".$activiteitID."'";
```

You're missing an equals on the last but one line:

```
werkzaamheid = '$werkzaamheid'
```

Comment: Wow how stupid is that....
Well i've added the = and now I get this error:

Unknown column 'datum' in 'field list'

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make - I think we've all done it. That error means that the `datum` field isn't in the database - is there a typo in the name, maybe?

Comment: Try echoing out the SQL you're generating, and running it directly in the database. It'll give you a better idea about where the problem is.

Comment: I echo'd the query. This gives: 
UPDATE vrijwilliger SET datum = '', tijd = '', vrijwilligerID = '', werkzaamheid = '' WHERE activiteitID = ''
Unknown column 'datum' in 'field list'

Comment: The database seems pretty sure there's no field called datum in the vrijwilliger table. It might be that `datum` is a reserved word in mySQL - try wrapping it in backticks in your query.

Comment: Ahhh, its correct that there is no datum in vrijwilliger, there is a datum in the table activiteit, which i'm trying to update.  I changed this, now it returns my query: UPDATE activiteit SET datum = '', tijd = '', vrijwilligerID = '', werkzaamheid = '' WHERE activiteitID = ''  so all my values are empty...

Comment: Your <form> is using `method='GET'`, but you're populating the variables with `$_POST` - switch those to `$_GET`, and it should find them. (You might also want to look into securing your form against SQL injections, but that's a whole other issue)

Comment: Thank you andrewsi, you are indeed right. Now my query recognises the values. The only one it is missing, is activiteitID, which actually is the most important of all.

Comment: You don't seem to be including activiteitID in your submission form - it probably should be in there as a hidden input?

Comment: Thank you very much andrew, sending and hidden input field worked, my database succesfully updates. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: No problem. Glad to have helped! (But you really should read up on SQL injection)

Comment: Don't worry, know how to do that too, but wanted to have this working first ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your missing an = in the update sql:

```
werkzaamheid '$werkzaamheid'
```

change to:

```
werkzaamheid = '$werkzaamheid'
```

BUT, you're passing _GET params directly to SQL which is a no-no.

Use PDO and parametrized queries instead:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM activiteit WHERE activiteitID = ?');
$sth->execute(array($activiteitID));

while($row = $sth->fetch()) {

}
```

Update your code similar to the above and it'll work. Do the same with the rest of your queries.